# MongoDB Aggregation push zero in keys while doing group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid6

I am not sure that this is a valid question or not. I have started working on mongodb aggregation. I have to make a graph for the data on daily, weekly, monthly basis.

I am using "**$dayOfMonth**", "**$week**", "**$month**" to group by depending on the date provided. ex if from and to dates difference is less or equal to 6 I am grouping on daily basis using "**$dayOfMonth**", 
If from and to dates difference is greater than 6 and less than 30 grouping is done of "**$week**" and if differece is greater than 30 then grouping is done on monthly basis "**$month**".

I am passing date in my "**$match**". Is it possible to push 0 as keys if the gouping is not present.

example -  from_date = "01/01/2018"   to_date = "30/6/2018"
so grouping will be done on month. and suppose if I dont have date for 3 and 4th & 5th month. I want to push 0 in the nested keys as the value.

```
    output = [
               {"_id": "01/01/2018", "counter":12}, 
               {"_id": "01/02/2018", "counter": 15}, 
               {"_id":"01/06/2018", counter: 10}
             ]

     expected_output = 
             [
              {"_id": "01/01/2018", "counter":12}, 
              {"_id": "01/02/2018", "counter": 15},
              {"_id":"01/03/2018", counter: 0},
              {"_id":"01/04/2018", counter:0},
              {"_id":"01/05/2018", counter: 0},
              {"_id":"01/06/2018", counter: 10}
             ]
```

I am using Rails and Mongoid Gem.
 Query That I am using

```
    converted = Analytics::Conversion::PharmacyPrescription.collection.aggregate([
       { "$match" => { 
            "organisation_id" => org_id.to_s, 
            "date" => {
              "$gte" => from_date, 
              "$lte" => to_date
            },
            "role_ids" => {"$in" => [role_id, "$role_ids"]}
          }
        },{
          "$project" => {
            "total_count" => 1,
            "converted_count" => 1,
            "not_converted_count" => 1,
            "total_invoice_amount" => 1,
            "user_id" => 1,
            "facility_id" => 1,
            "organisation_id" => 1,
            "date" => 1,
          }
        },{
          "$group" => {
            "_id" => { "#{groupby}" => "$date" },
            "total_count" => {"$sum" => "$total_count"},
            "converted_count" => { "$sum" => "$converted_count" },
            "not_converted_count" => { "$sum" => "$not_converted_count"},
          }
        }
    ]).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

The Aggregation Framework can only aggregate the **documents you have**. You are actually asking it to add groups for **documents that do not exist**, but it has no way to "know" which groups to add.

What I would do is run the query as you have it, and afterwards "spread" the date units according to the chosen granularity (in your example it will be 01/01/2018, 01/02/2018, 01/03/2018, 01/04/2018, 01/05/2018, 01/06/2018, and run a simple function which will add an entry for each missing unit.